# react-native-scrollable-tab-view can't click icon and didn't show content

Tags: react-native, react-native-scrollable-tab-view

I copy the [facebookBar Examle](https://github.com/ptomasroos/react-native-scrollable-tab-view/tree/master/Example) (FacebookExample.js and FacebookTabBar.js) into my project and I got the result like this

[image]

I can't click the icons and it did't show content. When I run the original project,it comes out correct like this

[image]

**EDIT**

Comment: @nemesv ok,I will add the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally find the answer from [click issue of react-native-scrollable-tab-view](https://github.com/ptomasroos/react-native-scrollable-tab-view/issues/965).

you should add style {flex: 1} in parent View

[image]